# "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (uri) module

Tags: ansible

> "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (uri) module: status Supported parameters include: attributes, backup, body, body_format, client_cert, client_key, content, creates, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, follow, follow_redirects, force, force_basic_auth, group, headers, http_agent, method, mode, owner, regexp, remote_src, removes, return_content, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, status_code, timeout, unix_socket, unsafe_writes, url, url_password, url_username, use_proxy, validate_certs"

Comment: `msg: "could not get a single clue about what could possibly be wrong without having any bloody information about what you are trying to do"`... besides the fact you are passing an unsupported parameter to uri module that is not in the litany of supported ones in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

As your message says the parameter for Uri module not supported is "status", change this to  **status_code**.
If you want to know which parameters are suported by the Uri module, go to Ansible reference and search module Uri parameters.
Let me know if this solve your problem.